# Docker container networks

Tags: docker, docker-network

With the release of docker 1.9 came container networks. I understand how to use them but i'm not sure why I should use them. what are the benefits of using  container networks?

Comment: The release blog post is a good summary https://blog.docker.com/2015/11/docker-multi-host-networking-ga/

Answer (score 0):

The main reason I uses container networks is so that I can give the containers the same IP's as real virtual machines. I use docker a lot to test salt-stack states. I put all the machines I want into a docker-compose file and use docker images with salt-master / salt-minion installed. I apply my states and I have a working copy of the target environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main benefits: containers isolation and communication in a clustered environment.

"Container networks" are virtual networks; they work on top of existing physical networks but allow you to create private networks that are only visible to the containers who are on that network. This isolation is an important security feature. You typically place all of your backend container services like database, indexing, app server in their own private network and only expose one container (nginx, apache, haproxy,...) to the outside world (public network).

Virtual networks also allow the creation of overlay networks, which permits containers in **different hosts** to communicate as if they we were on the same host. This is the basis for clustered solution like Docker Swarm.